# how can pass variable in html file with node js for sending mail

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am new to node.js.By using this code i am able to receive email. I don't know how to pass that "name" variable to html and get value of that variable in email.
Error is : Can't set headers after they are sent.
**app.js file**

```
mailer.extend(app, {
    from: 'mail@mail.com',
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com', // hostname 
  secureConnection: true, // use SSL 
  port: 465, // port for secure SMTP 
  transportMethod: 'SMTP', // default is SMTP. Accepts anything that nodemailer accepts 
  auth: {
    user: 'xxxxxxx',
    pass: 'xxxxxxx'
  }
});
app.engine('html', cons.swig)
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

**Rout.js file**

```
app.post("/registration", function(req, res) {
res.render('register', { name: firstName });
app.mailer.send('register', {
                    to: email, // REQUIRED. This can be a comma delimited string just like a normal email to field.  
                    subject: 'Test Email', // REQUIRED. 
                    otherProperty: 'Other Property' // All additional properties are also passed to the template as local variables. 

                },
                function (err) {
                        if (err) {

                          console.log(err);
                          res.send('There was an error sending the email');
                          return;
                        }


                        res.send({"code":1,"message":"Regestration Successfully."});
                        res.end();
                    });
```

**register.html file**

```
<body>
Dear {{ name }}
</body>
```

Comment: Check for typos, in render, you are passing `firstName`, yet in html you expect `name`

Comment: Error showing :Can't set headers after they are sent.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd try Octavio's suggestion.

I personally use either React or express-handlebars to get data onto the page. If you're saving this particular piece of data in a database you could always use an ajax call or perhaps just get the axios package if you don't want to deal with importing the entire jquery library.

I'd say check these sources out for more info.

- [Guide to using Express-Handlebars](https://github.com/EpicWiz/howto-node-sequelize-express-expressHB) - The most valuable part of this is the example. Scroll down for instructions on how to get it, or just download the example folder.
- [Express-Handlebars NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars)
- [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/)

It looks like you're using express already, so express-handlebars is probably the fastest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the html file and apply a string replace, assuming has a static "flags" like {{ name }}

js code:

```
const _fs = require('fs');
const _path = require('path');

var composeWithBasicTemplate = function (emailData, next) {
    var path = _path.join(__dirname, "email_templates/");
    _fs.readFile(path + 'basic.html', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            _console.log(err, 'error');

            return null;
        };

        data = data.replace('{TITLE}', emailData.ComposedTitle);
        data = data.replace('{TITLE}', emailData.ComposedTitle);
        data = data.replace('{BODY}', emailData.ComposedBody);
        data = data.replace('{URLACTION}', emailData.ComposedUrlAction);
        data = data.replace('{TEXTACTION}', emailData.ComposedTextAction);
        data = data.replace('{COPYRIGHTDATE}', (new Date()).getFullYear());

        next(data);
    });
}
```

html file:

```
...
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                                <tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                                    <td class="content-block" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 22px; text-align:center; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;" valign="top">
                                        {TITLE}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                                    <td class="content-block" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; text-align:center; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;" valign="top">
                                        {BODY}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                                    <td class="content-block" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; text-align:center; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;" valign="top">
                                        <a href="{URLACTION}" class="btn-primary" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; line-height: 2; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; border-radius: 0px; text-transform: capitalize; background: #d9534f; margin: 0; padding: 0; border-color: #d9534f; border-style: solid; border-width: 10px 20px;">{TEXTACTION}</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                                    <td class="content-block" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px; text-align:center;">
                                        <br /><br />
                                        <p class="MsoNormal" align="center"><a href="{URLCONFIG}"><img src="{URLCONFIG}/content/img/Home/LARNIA_logo.png" width="280" /></a></p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
...
```

Comment: i tried it but i can't enter in function part of your coding

Comment: Oh sorry, you can use it: composeWithBasicTemplate({emailData:{ComposedTitle: "Some Nice Title", ComposedBody: "Bla bla bla", ...}}, function(result){ /* Do Something with result*/}); you recieve two parameters, first is a email data, you can manipulate it and second is a callback if you need it (to return an alert, or something like that.)

Answer (score 0):

You set `app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');` so make sure that the html file exists in this directory, and the syntax for variable template is `<%=name%>`, such as:

```
<body>
    Dear<%= name %>
</body>
```